# Batch compiling only one project in a solution

Tags: c++, tfs, build

Say I have a solution that contains three projects

```
SolutionA
    ProjectA
    ProjectB
    ProjectC
```

The whole solution is set to build as AnyCPU.  However, ProjectB is a managed C++ project and I would like it (and only it) to build both Win32 and x64.  I am using TFS to perform these builds nightly.  Is there any good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .sln file itself cannot build same project in two configurations or platforms at the same time. One possible workaround is to create a custom project, that would be invoked by .sln and would call in its turn a projectA twice -- with two different values of Platform parameter. The custom project file would look like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == ''">Debug</Configuration>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="build">
        <MSBuild Project="ProjectA.vcxproj" Properties="Platform=Win32;Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
        <MSBuild Project="ProjectA.vcxproj" Properties="Platform=x64;Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

For this to work you need to do the following. 1. In the solution disable build of ProjectA (or remove it from .sln). 2. Add your custom project to the .sln.

Also, remember, you cannot pass explicit /p:Platform option to the